# time complexity of summing algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I've had a look through previous posts and I'm still struggling to find the T(n) and big O of these two recursive algorithms, each one takes a sequence of numbers as its argument and sums all numbers in the list (except for last item) then adds the sum to the last item. could anyone please shed some light.

```
def sum(numberSequence):
    assert (len(numberSequence) > 0)
    if (len(numberSequence) == 1):
        return numberSequence[0]
    else:
        return sum(numberSequence[-1]) + numberSequence[:-1]
```

(I believe the bigO is `O(n)` as in worst case, the function is called n-1 times, but not sure what happens when it is only summing part of the list. I have `T(n) = n x n-1 + n = O(n)` it just doesn't seem right).

```
def binarySum(numberSequence):
    assert (len(numberSequence) > 0)
    breakPoint = int(len(numberSequence)/2)
    if (len(numberSequence) == 1):
        return numberSequence[0]
    else:
        return binarySum(numberSequence[:breakPoint]) + binarySum(numberSequence[breakPoint:])
```

I'm more lost on this one, I think the big O is `O(log2 n)` as it is binary search but the whole list isn't being divided in half, only most of the list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're summing a list of `N` numbers of any size, in any order.

You aren't going to find a clever way to do that faster without some constraints.

It's `Ω(N)` always (lower bound is `N` addition operations - you won't get any better than that).

As a commenter below noted *your* algorithm may in fact be worse - it just can't be better.

Comment: Ha, yes, that is true. To be more correct it should be Ω(N).

Comment: Hi I wasn't trying to improve the algorithms, I'm just trying to figure out the T(n) and BigO for each one. I believe the bigO of the first one is O(n) but surely the second one has a different complexity?

Comment: @georgeT, no. Consider this case: binarySum([1,2,3,4]). Divide the list up: [1,2] [3,4]. And again: [1] [2] [3] [4].  Now there are 4 items. That's 2². You're going to add up 1+2 and 3+4. Then you'll add up 3 and 7. So you perform 2<sup>n</sup> -1 adds for a list of 2<sup>n</sup> elements. Still basically *O(n)*.

Comment: You can make it faster if you make the list update slower

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** corrections made based on comments regarding *O(n)* performance of [::].

**TL;DR:** It could be *O(n),* but your version is *O(n²).*

Remember that all of the big-O notations assume "times a constant". That is, *O(n)* really means *O(k * n)*, and *O(log n)* really means *O(k * log n)*.

Let's look at your first example:

```
def sum(numberSequence):
    assert (len(numberSequence) > 0)
    if (len(numberSequence) == 1):
        return numberSequence[0]
    else:
        return sum(numberSequence[-1]) + numberSequence[:-1]
```

The first line is `assert` plus `compare` plus `len`. The `len` operation is a constant time for lists and tuples (But it might not be with some other data structure! Beware!), compare is a constant time, and the assert is effectively a constant time, because if it ever fails the whole thing blows up and we stop computing. So let's just call `assert` a function call plus a comparison plus a return.

Now, how many times does this function get called? Well, the termination condition obviously represents one time, and every other time it's recursing on a list that is one shorter than the previous list. So the function will be called `len(numberSequence)` times, which is `n` for our purposes.

So we have

```
  1 * call (for the user calling us)
+ n * assert 
+ n * len 
+ n * compare
```

Next, we have the `if` statement that marks the termination condition for your recursion. Obviously, this statement will only be successful once (it's the **termination** condition, right? Only happens at the end...) so that's a comparison each time, and once per sum it's a return of a constant index.

```
  n * compare
+ 1 * constant index
+ 1 * return
```

Finally, there is the `else:` branch. I'm pretty sure you have a bug, and it should really be this (note position of colon):

```
        return sum(numberSequence[:-1]) + numberSequence[-1]
```

In that case you return the sum of a constant negative index lookup and a recursive function call of a slice. You only do this when it's NOT the end of the recursion, so `n-1` times.

```
  (n - 1) * constant negative index lookup
+ (n - 1) * slice
+ (n - 1) * recursive call
+ (n - 1) * return
```

**But wait!** If you look around for people asking about how to make a copy of a list, you'll find that one common Python idiom is `copy = orig[:]`. The reason for this is that a *slice* operation makes a copy of the subrange of the list it is slicing. So when you say `numberSequence[:-1]` what you're really saying is `copy = [orig[i] for i in range(0, len(orig)-1)]`.

This means that the `slice` operation is *O(n),* but on the plus side it's written in C. So the constant is a much smaller one.

Let's add those up:

```
  1 * call
+ n * assert 
+ n * len
+ n * compare
+ n * compare
+ 1 * constant index 
+ 1 * return
+ (n - 1) * constant negative index lookup
+ (n - 1) * (c * n) slice
+ (n - 1) * recursive call
+ (n - 1) * return
```

If we assume that *constant index* and *constant negative index* take the same time, we can merge them. We can obviously merge the returns and the calls. Which leaves us with:

```
   n * call
 + n * assert 
 + n * len
 + n * compare
 + n * compare
 + n * constant (maybe negative) index 
 + n * return
 + (n - 1) * (c * n) slice
```

Now according to "the rules," this is *O(n²)*. Which means that all the details of *O(n)* behavior fall by the wayside in favor of that big, fat *O(n²).*

**However:**

If the `len` operation were not *O(1)* - that is, constant time - then the function might well become *O(n²)* because of that.

If the `index` operations were not *O(1)*, because of underlying implementation details, the function might become *O(n²)* or *O(n log n)* because of that.

So you have implemented an algorithm that could be *O(n)* using a Python operator that is inherently *O(n)* itself. Your implementation is "inherently" *O(n²)*. But it can be fixed. Even if fixed, things outside of your control could make your code slower. (But, that's outside your control, so ... ignore it!)

How can we *fix* your code to make it *O(n)?* By getting rid of the slice! You don't need that anyway, right? You just need to track the range.

```
def sum(numberSequence, start=0, end=None):
    assert (len(numberSequence) > 0)
    if end is None:
        end = len(numberSequence) - 1
    if end == start:
        return numberSequence[start]
    else:
        return sum(numberSequence, start, end-1) + numberSequence[end]
```

In this code, I'm doing pretty much the same thing that you did, with two 
differences. First, I've added a special case to handle being called by an end user with only the sequence as an argument. And second, of course, there is no slice. With that out of the way, the code is no longer inherently *O(n²).*

You can do the same math, and make the same changes, to your other example, but it's more complex. However, I will remind you that the sum of 2<sup>i</sup> for i = 0..n-1 is 2<sup>n</sup> - 1. As @lollercoaster points out, there ain't no such thing as a free lunch: you have to add up all the numbers.

Comment: Yes, but these are numberSequences. Could be a list, could be ... meatcake. I have a particular fear of special-built classes with O(n) operations because of a traumatic adulthood experience...

Comment: Slicing is not constant time on any of the builtin sequence types. It's `O(N)`, making the whole algorithm `O(N**2)`.

Comment: @Blckknght slicing is constant time on `numpy` `array`s.

Comment: Well, I did say "builtin sequence", by which I meant `tuple` and `list`. Numpy is a whole different ballgame. I supposed Python 3's `range` objects also have constant time slices (and are builtin sequences), but that's really getting down in the weeds. My point is: this answer suggests that `len` may not be constant (though it is on all sequence types I'm aware of), but omits the same warning for slicing (which is is often, though not always, `O(N)`).

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the pointer, @Blckknght! I spaced on that, figuring that "surely" something like slicing would be COW.

Answer (score 0):

Technically I think the actual runtimes of your algorithms may both be worse than `O(n)`.  The slicing operation is `O(length_of_slice)`, since it copies the relevant portion of the list.  That said, since that happens in C under the hood, you may not notice the performance.

I'm torn on whether to count that fact in the runtime of your own algorithm, since if you implemented this e.g. in C with pointer arithmetic rather than Python with slicing, these would both be `O(n)`.

Two side notes:

- In your `sum` function, you slice the wrong sequence (should be `return sum(numberSequence[:-1]) + numberSequence[-1]`).
- In practice, you should just use the `sum` builtin rather than rolling your own like this.